# Variable is not increasing it's value on increment?

Tags: php, html

```
<?php 
    $cat = $obj->showcat();
    foreach($cat as $show){
?>

<div class="col-5">

<?php echo "<a href='category.html' class='mega-menu-title'>".$show['cname']."</a><!-- End .mega-menu-title -->";
?>      

<ul class="mega-menu-list clearfix">

<?php   
    $scat = $obj->showallcat($id=1);
    foreach($scat as $sshow){
    $id++;
    echo "<li><a href='#''>".$sshow['cname']."</a></li>";
}
?>

</ul>
</div>
<!-- End .col-5 -->
}
?>
```

i want my `$id` variable to increase it's value on it's parent for each loop but it is not happening since i am new with php anyone could get where i am doing mistake.

Comment: what you are getting if you print the $scat array?

Comment: You increment the `$id`, but you never used the incremented `$id`.

Comment: if you want to increment the $id to used in showallcat you should put it outside the second foreach. 
but you should explain more, what are you getting of with this code ?

Comment: Huge thanks @seifeddineBesbes i just did not used it outside that is why i was not getting proper result.

Comment: @kamran you should remove $id =1 inside the showallcat

Comment: Thanks i did already as you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$id=1 will set the value of the variable each time you enter the foreach loop. You can declare $id outside the foreach loop then increment it inside the foreach

```
<?php 
    $cat = $obj->showcat(); 
    $id = 1;
    foreach($cat as $show){ 
?>
```